# How Google Web App Form Check If A Value Already In Google Sheet Before Submit?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm making a Google Web App form and trying to make a form validation check if the code that user input is already in first column of Google Sheet or not. User only could submit the form if the code is not in Google Sheet. But my form keep submitting the form without checking it. Is there anything I did wrong? Your response will be appreciated :)

Here's the javascript sample code:

```
  function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
    google.script.run.processForm(formObject);
    if (typeof formObject === 'string') {
       alert(formObject);
     }else{
       alert("Your form is submitted. Thank you!");
       document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
     }
  }
```

Here's the .gs code:

```
function processForm(formObject) {
  var url =  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('url');
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var data = ws.getRange(5, 1, ws.getLastRow()-1, 1).getValues();
  
  var codeList = data.map(function(r){return r[0].toString; });
  var position = codeList.indexOf(formObject.code);         //the code that user input is a number
  
  if (position >-1){
    return "You already submit the form.";
  }else{
    ws.appendRow([formObject.code, formObject.name, formObject.things]);
  }
```

**MODIFIED ANSWER**

Based on @Tanaike answer I modified a bit for my need:

Here's the Javascript code:

```
function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(e => {
    if (e) {
      alert("The code is already exist.");
    } else {
      alert("Your form is submitted. Thank you!");
      document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
    }
  }).processForm(formObject);
}
```

Here's the .gs code:

```
function processForm(formObject) {
  var url = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('url');
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var data = ws.getRange(2, 1, ws.getLastRow()-1, 1).getValues();
  var codeList = data.map(function(r){return r[0].toString()});
  var position = codeList.indexOf(formObject.code);
  if (position >-1){
    return true;
  } else {
    ws.appendRow([formObject.code, formObject.name, formObject.things]);
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I saw your script, it seems that the existence of the value is checked with `if (position >-1){}` in Google Apps Script. I think that this can be used for your goal. So how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

Javascript:

```
function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(e => {
    if (e) {
      alert(formObject);
    } else {
      alert("Your form is submitted. Thank you!");
      document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
    }
  }).processForm(formObject);
}
```

Google Apps Script:

```
function processForm(formObject) {
  var url =  PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('url');
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var data = ws.getRange(5, 1, ws.getLastRow()-1, 1).getValues();
  
  var codeList = data.map(function(r){return r[0].toString; });
  var position = npkList.indexOf(formObject.code);         //the code that user input is a number
  
  if (position >-1){
//    return "You already submit the form.";
    return true;
  } else {
    ws.appendRow([formObject.code, formObject.name, formObject.things]);
    return false;
  }
}
```

- By above modification, when `position > -1` is `true`, `true` is returned to Javascript. And `alert(formObject)` is run. When `position > -1` is `false`, `false` is returned to Javascript. And `alert("Your form is submitted. Thank you!")` and `document.getElementById("myForm").reset()` are run.

#### Reference:

- [Class google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

### Added:

When I saw your shared Spreadsheet, the data in "Sheet1" starts from row 2. But in your script, it is 5. By this, the existing data is not checked. And `r[0].toString;` is not run the method. So please add `()`. When these are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

Javascript:

```
function handleFormSubmit(formObject) {
  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(e => {
    if (e) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(formObject));
    } else {
      alert("Your form is submitted. Thank you!");
      document.getElementById("myForm").reset();
    }
  }).processForm(formObject);
}
```

Google Apps Script:

```
function processForm(formObject) {
  var url = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties().getProperty('url');
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);
  var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var data = ws.getRange(2, 1, ws.getLastRow()-1, 1).getValues();
  var codeList = data.map(function(r){return r[0].toString()});
  var position = codeList.indexOf(formObject.code);         //the code that user input is a number
  if (position >-1){
//    return "You already submit the form.";
    return true;
  } else {
    ws.appendRow([formObject.code, formObject.name, formObject.things]);
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your response.. I already try and learn your modification but with that code, the form will be submitted whether the "position" is found or not. Thats why I tried to return the alert string "You already submit the form." in my code but it didnt work as well haha

Comment: do you think there's something wrong with the data.map or the indefOf? By the way I just edit my indexOf it should be codeList.indexOf but still doesnt work

Comment: @Ray Thank you for replying. In your case, it is required to check the Spreadsheet. By this, I proposed to process it in the function of `processForm`. About `Thats why I tried to return the alert string "You already submit the form." in my code but it didnt work as well haha`, I cannot understand about your current situation. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this. In order to correctly understand about it, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet including the your current script for replicating your issue? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Thank you for your good intention to help me :) I hope it will be clearer with this sample provided: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VFdqEIDqJ9KEieLpNaiDeIqNMKcy5LIa09r_-9FYGQM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @Ray Thank you for replying and adding more information. From your additional information, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: Ahh I see.. I misspelled the  row and the toString(), I modified a bit from your code and I already got what I want! Thank you so much for helping me!